# How to track not GUI events in QT creator?

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator

How to check a changes in NON-GUI classes, I wanna check updates of COM ports in infinity loop, but if I am doing it, my app is freezing and crushed.

---

I tried to use QThread but it didn't solve the problem

Main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "CheckPortsThread.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    checkPorts ports;
    w.show();
    ports.run();
    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSerialPort>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSerialPort *serial;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#define Debug

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serial = new QSerialPort;
    QString description;

    QList<QSerialPortInfo> serialPortInfos = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

    int portsNumber = serialPortInfos.count();

    #ifdef Debug
    qDebug() << "Total numbers of ports: " << portsNumber;
    #endif
    if (portsNumber > 0){
        for (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo : qAsConst(serialPortInfos))
         {
            description = serialPortInfo.portName() + "  [" + serialPortInfo.description() +"]" ;

            #ifdef Debug
            qDebug() << "Port: "<< description << endl;
            #endif
        }
        ui->comboBox->addItem(description);
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

CheckPortsThread.h

```
#ifndef CHECKPORTSTHREAD_H
#define CHECKPORTSTHREAD_H

#endif // CHECKPORTSTHREAD_H

#include <QtCore>


class checkPorts: public QThread{
public:
    checkPorts();
    void run() override;


};
```

CheckPortsThread.cpp

```
#include "CheckPortsThread.h"

void checkPorts::run(){
    while (true){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        qDebug() << i << endl;
    }
}
checkPorts::checkPorts(){}
```

**So run() method crushed the program**

Comment: I mean an infinity loop is a problem that crushes my program, but how to check com updates otherwise ?

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand the question but... if you want notification of any changes etc. on a specific serial port then create a `QSerialPort` instance and connect to one or more of its [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html#signals).

Comment: I wanna check weather a new port was added or not

Comment: Maybe add a timer and check periodically? Like, the run() function, without the while loop being executed on a timer

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the ::run method of your QThread derived class, therefore no Thread is actually started, the run method is simply called from the mainthread.

To get it running in a thread call `checkPorts.start()` instead.